# tasks for stack in VS code

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am new to VS code (1.21.1) with HIE 0.1.0.0 - installed using stack. I have been able to define a task for testing:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "test",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "stack build --test",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I checked the documentation mentioned but did not understand much. 
This task works only on the project I specified it for; how to make it usable for any project I happen to have open in the editor? How to further automate the selection of tasks?

I assume that there is somewhere a collection of tasks to run stack with HIE - could somebody point me to it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the problem you run into, but Visual Studio Code gives you the ability to edit settings per work-space/project in addition to overall settings:

[image: Visual Studio Code User Settings and Workspace Settings tabs]

Make sure that you're editing the *USER SETTINGS* tab instead of the *WORKSPACE SETTINGS* tab, if you want the settings to all projects.

Apologies if this is a trivial answer, and the problem is something completely different.

Comment: thank you for your information, which might be part of my question. When I look at the serttings in the tab you indicate, I do not find the build commands. Where are they hidden? I have the impression, that the tasks are not stored in the workspace or user settings?